# how to change the color of every occurrence of a specific character in a html page ? (eg for '*')

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Like for example instead of using font tag and color attribute before every occurrence of '*' in my html page i want to simply use some lines of code to make them red.

```
<div class="col-md-1" align="right">Area * </div>
       <div class="col-md-4">
          <select class="form-control" id="area" name="area">
               <option>--Select--</option>
          </select>
       </div>
   </div>
    <br>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2"><p id="desc_error" class="text-danger"></p></div>
        <label class="col-md-2">Description *</label>
        <div class="col-md-5">
            <textarea id="desc" class="form-control" name="desc" rows="10" cols="10s" style="resize: none"
          data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="focus" data-placement="right" data-content="To get more relevant responses provide additional details like prerequisites, qualification details and all other needs that you want."></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2"><p id="exp_error" class="text-danger"></p> </div>
        <label class="col-md-2">Job Expires in *</label>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Doing it with CSS, I would take this approach:

```
<div><span>Area</span></div>


 div > span:after {
    content: "*";
    color: red;
 }
```

Comment: Seems it's only partially supported from IE8, though. 9 and up are fine. *edit*: nm. The double colon is what's partially supported. The above approach works fine.

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_after.asp

Comment: Double colon notation has been introduced in CSS Selectors 3, but single colon notation (as per CSS2.1) is still accepted. IE8 supports only CSS2.1 with old (single colon) notation. IE7- doesn't support pseudo elements at all.